# Do Magento CE extensions work in PE?

Tags: magento

Do Magneto CE extensions work in PE? The extensions I've tried installing in PE aren't working (they install but yield blank screens) and I can't find a straight answer; don't know if it's a problem on my end or if it's built in to Magento. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes. CE modules can function correctly as part of PE, but it will depend greatly on what parts of the functionality it touches.

Answer (score 0):

Things to do for any Magento issues like this:

1. Ensure the extension is enabled (check to ensure it's output is enabled and it's active) - see [this post for reference](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-fully-disable-turn-off-magento-module/) (the post is how to turn off an extension, but it will point you in the right direction)
2. Refresh your cache
3. Ensure logging is [on](http://alanstorm.com/magento_log_and_developer_mode) and check your logs for errors
4. Check your web server logs - where these are will depend on which web server you are running. Apache logs are generally in the error.log file under /var/logs/apache2 or /var/log/httpd
5. If all else fails, start debugging, by putting Mage::log() entries into the code and seeing what is logged and what isn't

Answer (score 0):

Any extension could possibly work in any version, even if it isn't listed as such. Generally developers of extensions just list the versions that it has been tested in, but that doesn't mean it cant be used in others.

Best way to find out is install the module in your **dev environment**, and test to make sure it isn't overwriting/breaking any of the existing functionality.